# plot multiple boxplot in one graph ( one column is list of data) by Plotly or other way

Tags: python, dataframe, plotly, boxplot

I don't know how to plot multiple boxplot in one graph by Plotly. I guess the point is that the value in the 'list_hour' column is the list. My dataframe is like this:

```
      Main_Category list_hour   
   0    Active Life [22, 21, 18, 23, 20, 5, 13, 12, 20, 0, 22, 19,...
   1    Auto Repair [17, 15, 19, 23, 16, 22, 22, 19, 15, 20, 18, 1...
   2    Automotive  [17, 18, 19, 0, 20, 5, 23, 17, 15, 18, 22, 16,...
   3    Beauty & Spas   [17, 18, 17, 0, 4, 16, 17, 23, 23, 23, 18, 2, ...
   4    Event Planning & Services   [22, 20, 1, 17, 1, 4, 18, 20, 18, 17, 21, 5, 2...
   5    Fast Food   [17, 2, 2, 2, 5, 5, 2, 2, 7, 10, 2, 2, 22, 1, ...
   6    Food    [21, 17, 0, 23, 5, 2, 3, 19, 22, 22, 0, 19, 22...
   7    Hair Salons [17, 23, 18, 3, 0, 0, 23, 6, 23, 15, 19, 7, 3,...
   8    Health & Medical    [10, 21, 18, 18, 20, 14, 15, 22, 18, 23, 15, 1...
   9    Home Services   [2, 2, 3, 16, 4, 20, 14, 1, 2, 20, 2, 21, 7, 1...
   10   Local Services  [2, 17, 2, 15, 15, 15, 20, 21, 15, 17, 18, 1, ...
   11   Nightlife   [23, 13, 2, 1, 13, 3, 5, 19, 3, 3, 19, 22, 18,...
   12   Pizza   [18, 23, 0, 4, 20, 17, 3, 19, 2, 20, 20, 23, 4...
   13   Restaurants [16, 0, 16, 16, 15, 21, 22, 18, 7, 15, 23, 1, ...
   14   Shopping    [0, 22, 18, 23, 17, 14, 21, 19, 2, 22, 3, 21, ...
```

Or is there any other way to plot multiple boxplot for this dataframe instead of Plotly? Appreciate your help!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the way I solve this problem.

`nn = list_hour_df.explode('list_hour').reset_index(drop=True)`

`nn['list_hour'] = nn['list_hour'].astype(int)`

`nn`

```
0   Active Life     22
1   Active Life     21
2   Active Life     18
3   Active Life     23
4   Active Life     20
... ... ...
396416  Shopping    8
396417  Shopping    13
396418  Shopping    21
396419  Shopping    19
396420  Shopping    4
```

`fig = px.box(nn, x="list_hour", y="Main_Category")`

`fig.show()`
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TVaCa.png)